# i want to know how to send message to us numbers using toll free number i

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I tried this code but in sns console it shows it failed. I want to know how to send message using TFN number

```js
async sendMessage(testId: number) {
  const mobileNo = test.customer.phoneNo;
  const params = {
    Message: `A backflow test was completed successfully `,
    PhoneNumber: '+17711111113',

    MessageAttributes: {
      'AWS.MM.SMS.OriginationNumber': {
        DataType: 'String',
        StringValue: '+12012345563',
      },
    },
  };
  return new AWS.SNS({
      apiVersion: '2010–03–31'
    })
    .publish(params)
    .promise()
    .then((message) => {
      console.log('Message SEND SUCCESS');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      return err;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the mobileNo to the PhoneNumber field in the params and format the PhoneNumer to be in E.164 format. The AWS.MM.SMS.OriginationNumber should be a TFN

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

async function sendMessage(testId: number) {
  const mobileNo = test.customer.phoneNo;
  const params = {
    Message: `A backflow test was completed successfully `,
    PhoneNumber: '+1' + mobileNo, // Assuming mobileNo is in E.164 format without the country code
    MessageAttributes: {
      'AWS.MM.SMS.OriginationNumber': {
        DataType: 'String',
        StringValue: '+12012345563', // Your TFN number in E.164 format
      },
    },
  };
  return new AWS.SNS({
    apiVersion: '2010-03-31'
  })
    .publish(params)
    .promise()
    .then((message) => {
      console.log('Message SEND SUCCESS');
      return message;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      throw err;
    });
}
```

Comment: it is already in e.16 format only could you please explain to to me thankyou

Comment: Ensure that:
AWS is correctly imported and configured with your AWS credentials.
test object and its properties like test.customer.phoneNo are correctly defined and populated before calling sendMessage.
Your TFN (AWS.MM.SMS.OriginationNumber) is set up correctly in AWS SNS and has SMS capabilities enabled.